# Windows 10 Toast Notification Visuals and Actions not working

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-10, toast, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing a c# console application that sends toast notifications in VS2017 on a Windows 10 machine. When I run my code and have only defined adaptive text content for my notification it runs correctly and displays the desired text. If I add actions, it no longer displays the adaptive text I defined ("title" and "content" below), nor does it have the option to perform said actions. If I try to add additional visuals such as a logo or picture, they do not appear but the adaptive text is unaffected.

```
string category = "Notifications";

string title = "New Test Notification!;

string content = "Testing push notifications!";

ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
        {
            Visual  = new ToastVisual()
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = title
                        },

                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = content
                        }

                    },
                    /*AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                    {
                        Source = "https://unsplash.it/64?image=883",
                        HintCrop = ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle
                    }*/
                }
            },

        /*Actions  = new ToastActionsCustom()
        {
            Buttons =
            {
                new ToastButton("check", "check")
                {
                    ImageUri = "check.png"
                },

                new ToastButton("cancel", "cancel")
                {
                    ImageUri = "cancel.png"
                }
             }
        }*/
    };

    string toastXml = toastContent.GetContent();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(toastXml);
    var toast = new ToastNotification(doc);

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(category).Show(toast);
```

Result when above code is run with or without the first block of commented code: [image]

Result when code is run with the second block of commented code: [image]